# Service fails to Start in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-manifest

Im a beginner in android. Trying to start a service from MainActivity but it fails. Here is the calling method a button onClick listener

```
@Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class);
                try
                {
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to start MyService", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
```

The Service is as below

```
public class MyService extends Service
```

{

```
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId)
{
    // TODO: Implement this method
    super.onStart(intent, startId);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onStart method in MyServive class", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent p1)
{
    // TODO: Implement this method
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onBind method in MyServive class", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    // TODO: Implement this method
    super.onCreate();

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onCreate method in MyServive class", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    // TODO: Implement this method
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onStartCommand method in MyServive class", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    // TODO: Implement this method
    super.onDestroy();

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onDestroy method in MyServive class", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

The manifest declaration is below

```
<Service
        android:enabled="true"
        android:name=".MyService"
        android:label="MyService"
        >
    </Service>
```

What may be making it not to start? No toast is shown for any of the methods

Comment: For starting service you should use startService instead of startActivity

Answer (score 0):

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class);
            try
            {
                startService(i);

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to start MyService", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Post Your Main Activity Code here.